# li width displayed correctly in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, html-lists

I'm learning CSS and at the same time developing a simple library website. But I'm having some trouble.

1. Determining the li width. When I zoom in, there will be a white space on the right side of the navigation menu. But this happen only in chrome but not in firefox.

   Here is the link : [Bangda](http://www.gadgetcote.com/bangda)

   How to work this around ?
2. There is extra white footer at the bottom of the page. I think it is because the page resolution (or not?). But if I go to menu "Buku", the white space at the bottom of the page dissapear. Where do I do wrong ?

Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not seeing any white piece on the version of chrome that I'm running... could you post a screencap of it so we can see what you're talking about?
2. Since the white space disappears when you visit a different page that means that there is a difference in the way that you had the page set up between the two pages. It could be as simple as removing a space that you accidently put into a line. I'd suggest checking the Buku page against the home page and find where your difference in your navigation are.

But if you're looking for a quick-fix, just remove .1em's from your line-height.

```
    ul.dropdown li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Hrothmar. Thanks for your feedback. I have found where the mistake is, it's in my css. Thanks again for the responses